# Irreducibility of variety of intersecting linear spaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry, grassmannian

For the purposes of my research, I want to know if for any choices of dimensions $d_i,d_I\in \mathbb N\cup\{-1\},$
$$\mathcal V:=\{(L_1,\ldots,L_m):L_i\in \mathrm{Gr}(d_i,\mathbb P^n), \dim L_I\ge d_I\},$$
is an irreducible variety, where $L_I=\cap_{i\in I}L_i$ is the intersection of the linear spaces $L_i$ for $i\in I\subseteq [m]$.

Putting $d_I$ to $-1$ here means that there is no condition on how $L_i$ for $i\in I$ intersect.

I'm sure the answer to this question is stated in the literature, but I don't know where to look. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hint: consider the variety of all $(L_i,L_I)$, its projection to the Grassmannian parameterizing $L_I$, and study the fibers.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about the Grassmannian parametrizing $L_I$. In the example of four lines $L_1,L_2,L_3,L_4$ in $\mathbb P^3$, where $L_1,L_2,L_3$ meet $L_4$ in a point, we get a variety of all $(L_i,L_I)$ in $\mathrm{Gr}(1,\mathbb P^3)^4\times (\mathbb P^3)^3$. What exactly is the projection you are refering to?

Comment: Probably, I don't understand your notation. My impression was that you mean that you fix (a bound for) the dimension of the intersection of all your subspaces. Or do you mean you bound the dimension of intersection for all sets of subspaces?

Comment: Let $\mathcal I$ be a set of subsets of $\{1,\ldots,m\}$. Then I require that $\dim L_I\ge d_I$ precisely for $I\in \mathcal I$. So I choose these bounds for some intersections. By putting $d_I=-1$, the condition $\dim L_I\ge d_I$ is empty.

Comment: OK. My comment probably does not apply in general, but it does apply if the set of conditions you impose is "independent", i.e., if you have a disjoint set $I_1,\dots,I_k$ for which $d_I \ge 0$. Then it makes sense to add the corresponding $L_I$ to your data and consider two projections.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following example showing that $\mathcal V$ is not always irreducible. In $\mathbb P^3$ consider three lines $L_1,L_2,L_3$ with the condition that they pairwise intersect in points. This variety has two components: one where all $L_i$ are coplanar, and one where $L_i$ all meet in one point.